# Java stream filter null pointer issue

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following stream:

```
services = services.stream()
        .filter(service -> (service.getType().isEmpty() || service.getType().equals(type)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `service.type` is string, and `type` is also a string. My filter should return all services with its `type` equal to null (or simply blank), or the given type.

This throws me an error of:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.eternity.service.OrderService.lambda$getServicesForOrder$0(OrderService.java:140)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]    at
>   com.eternity.service.OrderService.getServicesForOrder(OrderService.java:141)
>   ~[classes/:na]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to debug ? Never tried on a lambda expression to be fair.

Answer (score 8):

The issue was: I was using `.isEmpty()` on a null object. I had to use `StringUtils.isEmpty()` method:

```
services = services.stream()
        .filter(service -> (StringUtils.isEmpty(service.getType()) || service.getType().equals(type)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could have also pre-filtered out the null objects with `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: In case the whole object is not null, the attribute you are trying to access might be null.
As here service.getType could give a null value.
Can be filtered with ``.filter(service -> service.getType() != null)``

Answer (score 0):

Too late for an answer but still posting this here if anyone comes across this post.
Try to use `filter` out all the `objects` which are `null` or have some `property` that can be null, before performing any operations on the same.

In this case

```
list.stream()
    //.filter(Objects::nonNull) // use when the whole object can be null    
    .filter(service->Objects.nonNull(service.getType()))
    .filter(service -> (service.getType().isEmpty() || service.getType().equals("Type1")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```